# Como utilizar Pusher JS ilimitadamente con servidor Websocket propio

Tags: javascript, laravel, angular, ionic

Tengo una aplicación de Angular que deseo conectar con un servidor websockets realizado con laravel-websockets. la configuración realizada en PUSHER JS en la aplicación IONIC es:

[image: Configuración de WebSocket en el Aplicación Angular]

teniendo en cuenta que tengo mi propio servidor websocket, puedo utilizar funciones ilimitadas de PusherJS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si estas utilizando la documentación y el repositorio de:

[Laravel websockets](https://docs.beyondco.de/laravel-websockets/)

Por supuesto que puedes consumir los websockets solo limitado por la capacidad de tu servidor. Pues como lo aclara en la documentación este paquete se encarga de administrar los websockets. Siendo un sustituto de los servicios de PUSHER.

Si tienes dudas sobre la implementación podría orientarte pero necesitaras ser mas especifico en donde estas atorado.

Saludos.

Comment: Mil gracias por tu respuesta. La duda principal que tengo, es en el primer parámetro que pide pusher (APP_KEY), que siempre me lo pide como obligatorio. Si utilizo Laravel-websockets, puedo dejarlo en blanco?

Comment: no pero le tienes que poner uno aleatorio

Comment: Perfecto!. Gracias!

Comment: debes de poner cualquier cosa. El campo lo llenas aleatoriamente y aun así funciona.